# Atari SM144 Horizontal lines after turning off then on

Tags: crt-monitor, atari

I recently bought an Atari SM144 monochrome monitor so I could play with an old Atari ST. It *works* to a certain degree, it turns on all good and I can play for a while, but after some time it gives off an ionising/burning smell.

It working (ignore the refresh rate discrepancy, it's a solid picture my end)

[image]

Then after let's say 5-10 minutes, maybe less if I turn off the monitor by the switch on the front, and then turn it back on, I get lines like the following

[image]

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Sounds like one or more broken solder points. The ozone smell could indicate that the problem is in the high voltage part of the system. Nothing I would recommend to try to fix yourself. Opening a CRT is really only for those who know exactly what they are doing.

Comment: I've already had it to bits cleaned and replaced most of the capacitors @UncleBod

Comment: Did you replace them with correct types? How did you know the caps needed replacing? Which caps you replaced, only the electrolytics, or all the plastic and ceramic caps too?

Comment: The image shows a missing horizontal synchronization. Since you _seem_ to have some electronic understanding, grab the schematic and your oscilloscope and try to find the reason. If you don't have both, better hand the device to someone more experienced. High voltages inside a CRT monitor are really dangerous, not to mention the mains supply waiting to bite you.

Comment: Replaced like for like @Justme. The capacitance reading was low on a few of them, nothing drastic. Was more just an excuse to use my new solder 

Comment: This may sound like a stupid question, but did it work properly before recapping it? Just to know if that has anything to do with it. Also, if you changed the mains filter caps, you did replace them with equal or better class safety rating, instead of random non-safety class caps not intended for mains voltage?

Comment: yeah the behaviour is exactly the same as before/after the recapping. @Justme I.e the turning off/on problem causing the striped screen.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope @thebusybee and I understand the dangers of working with a CRT monitor.

Comment: Well, you need to be sure that the input signal is valid first. You need some measurement equipment for this, without you're lost. Since there are no traces of non-white pixels, it might as well be the computer that crashed because of the power cycle of the monitor. Did you try to restart the computer?

Comment: yeah restarting the computer doesn't change anything, still get the same horizontal lines moving up the screen @thebusybee

Comment: Well, then... get a scope and dive into the circuit. Our crystal balls are in quarantine, again. What else can we do for you?

Comment: That's fair enough, I posted the question to see if anybody had had the same issue as me and could point me in the right direction. @thebusybee

Comment: "*Our crystal balls are in quarantine, again*" No need to be so gleefully sarcastic, @thebusybee. OP has a problem and it may be that a member here has experience with this monitor and would like to help, as often happens here with equipment questions. If that's not you then it can be left for someone who is.

Comment: @TonyM By the information provided the error could have a lot of possible reasons. It seems as if we have checked any that can be checked without further details or measures. The OP apparently refrains from doing more, so I shrugged in that way.

Comment: The SM144 has a service manual which tells you which signals to check but that does require a scope and knowing how to work with high voltages. It may still be useful because it lists the components that might be at fault according to the diagnosis. Also if the signals are merely off due to age it should be possible to adjust it to get a picture again and that will tell you much. Not sure I'd read too much into the burning smell, could be caps or resistors but Atari monitors always smell funny.